# RabbitMQ server thinks that it has delivered messages, RabbitMQ client disagrees

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using RabbitMQ to deliver messages to worker processes (using the official C# client). I have been running simple tests during the implementation, and all has been going swimmingly until now.

I ran a test where I queued messages for a worker process that was not listening (no connection). Once I had queued several hundred messages, I started that process. It created its IModel, declared its queue (which already existed), and began consuming messages (with BasicConsume). This went great. This process, as it processed messages, created messages for other queues. There were processes already listening to these queues (with BasicConsume), and so the messages were immediately delivered to those clients (or so the server thought...). The messages are never processed.

The server definitely believes that the messages have been delivered (the messages are all in the "unacked" bucket, not the "ready" bucket), but 
**IBasicConsumer.HandleBasicDeliver never got called on the client.** I have tried several different techniques (using a Subscription, using QueueingBasicConsumer as well as my own custom consumer), and the outcome is exactly the same. I'm at a complete loss. If I close the connection (there is only one connection here), then the messages immediately move from the "unacked" bucket to the "ready" bucket".

Why doesn't the client get notified when messages are delivered?

Looking into the code, ModelBase.Close() calls `ConsumerDispatcher.Shutdown()` (ModelBase.cs line 301), and from there, it calls `workService.StopWork()` (ConcurrentConsumerDispatcher.cs line 27). It seems to me (by a cursory view of the code) that this stops ALL work in the connection's ConsumerWorkService. Instead, should `ConcurrentConsumerDispatcher.Shutdown()` be calling `workService.StopWork(this)` on line 27?

Comment: It looks like you are missing an ack somewhere. Why not use something like Shuttle which handles everything for you? It will safe you lots of issues, https://github.com/Shuttle

Comment: See bolded part. I'm not missing an ack. Why not use Shuttle? Because it doesn't meet my needs. I don't need an ESB, I need a message queuing system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the RabbitMQ client, and a fix [has already been merged in](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/pull/62/files).

It should be available in the next nightly build, on 4/18/2015.

Answer (score 0):

If your BasicConsume defines `noAck = false`, after you Dequeues a message needs to run the next code:`channel.BasicAck(result.DeliveryTag, false);`

If your BasicConsume defines `noAck = true`, after you Dequeues a message it's removed from the server automatically.

Comment: All delivered messages are being acked.